# Send data to fragment from activity using viewmodels

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to display my data in my main activity using a fragment instead of starting an activity. This is my main activity screen

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBg"
    tools:context=".ui.search.SearchActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/teamsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In my main activity class I have the following 
   private void goToFragmentClass(Watch watch) {

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    viewModel.getTeamById(thisTeam.getTeamId()).observe(this, new Observer<Team>() {
        String json = "";
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Team team) {
            if (team != null)
                json = gson.toJson(team);
            else
                json = gson.toJson(thisTeam);


            //intent.putExtra("Watch", json);
           // startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

My question is how can I start commit the fragment in here and pass the `json` to the fragment class I know how to do this using the Activity but I want to use a fragment instead.

my viewmodel class

```
public class SearchViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MainRepository mainRepository;

    public SearchViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mainRepository = new MainRepository(application);
    }

    LiveData<List<Team>> getTeamList(String teamName) {
        return mainRepository.getTeamByName(teamName);
    }

    LiveData<Team> getTeamById(String id) {
        return mainRepository.getTeam(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you observing your data in viewModel or Activity?

Comment: just using `shared viewmodel`. Could you show your viewmodel class for activity?

Comment: added please check above

Comment: @Keshav1234 in the activity see my viewmodel

Comment: @AnnaMurray you are getting json from your oberver right so that is an activity. You can send the data to fragment using Bundle

Answer (score 1):

You can send Data to Fragment from Activity using Bundle.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(KEY, json);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
//Perform Fragment add/replace using fragment transaction here.
```

In your Fragment:

```
if (arguments != null)
String json = getArguments.getString(KEY, json)
```

Hope this helps